# Maximum of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ in the closed unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have some trouble with the following question:

> Let
>   $$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z},\quad\text{for }z\in\mathbb{C}.$$
>   What is the maximum of $f$ in the closed unit disc
>   $$D:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}?$$

Of course, we can apply the Maximum Modulus Principle to get that
$$\max_{z\in D}|f(z)|=\max_{|z|=1}\frac{|\sin z|}{|z|}=\max_{|z|=1}|\sin z|$$
But then I don't see any easy way to find the maximum of $\sin z$ on the unit circle. I ploted the graph and I found that it is
$$|\sin i|=\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}$$
Here is my attempt to prove it:

Let $F(\theta)=|f(e^{i\theta})|^2$. Then,
\begin{align}
F(\theta) &= |\sin(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)|^2 \\
&= |\sin(\cos\theta)\cosh(\sin\theta)+i\cos(\cos\theta)\sinh(\sin\theta)|^2 \\
&= \sin^2(\cos\theta)\cosh^2(\sin\theta)+\cos^2(\cos\theta)\sinh^2(\sin\theta) \\
&=\sin^2(\cos\theta)\cosh^2(\sin\theta)+(1-\sin^2(\cos\theta))\sinh^2(\sin\theta) \\
&=\sin^2(\cos\theta)\big(\cosh^2(\sin\theta)-\sinh^2(\sin\theta)\big)+\sinh^2(\sin\theta) \\
&= \sin^2(\cos\theta)+\sinh^2(\sin\theta) 
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
F'(\theta) &= -2\sin(\cos\theta)\cos(\cos\theta)\sin\theta+2\sinh(\sin\theta)\cosh(\sin\theta)\cos\theta \\
&=\sinh(2\sin\theta)\cos\theta-\sin(2\cos\theta)\sin\theta
\end{align}
which vanishes whenever
$$\theta=\frac{n\pi}{2},\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
Then, we try and find
$$F(0)=\sin^2 1,\quad F(\pi/2)=\sinh^2 1,\quad F(\pi)=\sin^21,\quad F(3\pi/2)=\sinh^21$$
But $\sin^21<\sinh^21$ (which I am not sure how to justify with only pen and paper) so the maximum is with $\theta=\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$. This gives the desired result.

**This seems overly complicated for this kind of problem. Is there a better way?**

Comment: Should the question ask for the maximum of $|f|$?

Comment: @alex.jordan It is a standard terminology that the "maximum" of a holomorphic function means the maximum of its absolute value. It is not ambiguous since it is a fact that there does not exist any total ordering on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you know the ["maximum modulus principle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Oups, I meant "maximum modulus principle" and not "mean value property". As you can see, I used the former, not the later. I will edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Taylor series for $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ has all its terms real and positive when $z=i$, and the corresponding terms are the same in magnitude for any $z$ on the unit circle, so the maximum has to occur for $z=i$.

Comment: This answer is great because it enlightened me to a new way of looking at the behavior holomorphic functions. I am sure this kind approach will be useful for me later. Many thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Use the series expansion (if we can use):
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!},\qquad\sin z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}z^{2n-1},\forall z\in \mathbb{C}.$$
So, when $|z|=1$,
$$|\sin z|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}z^{2n-1}\right|
\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}.$$
Obviously, we have
$$|\sin(\pm i)|=\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}.$$
So
$$\max_{|z|=1}|\sin z|=|\sin (i)|=\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach, since $z=x+iy$, then

> $$ \max_{|z|=1}|\sin(z)|= \max \left\{\sqrt{\cosh(y)^2-\cos(x)^2}\right\},\quad x^2+y^2 = 1.  $$

Now, we need to maximize the above function over the unit circle $x^2+y^2= 1$. We can use optimization techniques (see multivariable calculus). Here is an answer by Maple

> $$ \rm {Max:} \sim 1.1752, (x=0,y=1)$$

**Note:** To make the calculations easier, you can just find the maximum of the function

> $$ \cosh(y)^2-\cos(x)^2, \quad x^2+y^2 = 1, $$

then take the square root of the answer.